# Crossreferencing included PDFs in the appendix for classicthesis + lyx

Tags: hyperref, lyx, labels, pdfpages, classicthesis

My appendix currently consists of 4 PDF's that I have manually included into the "Appendix" Part of my tex document created in Lyx (classicthesis v4.1). I would like to cross-reference these included PDF's in my text. I am currently adding labels above the `pdfbookmark[]` and `\includepdf[]` statements for each PDF I am including, but referencing these labels in-text only returns me to the "Appendix" level, and not the specific PDF when I compile my document and click on the in-text link. MVE below, showing 2 example included files:

```
\appendix
\part{Appendix}

\label{SOP052}
\pdfbookmark[1]{SOP052}{SOP052}
\includepdf[pages=-]{"SOP052"}

\label{SOP054}
\pdfbookmark[1]{SOP054}{SOP054}
\includepdf[pages=-]{"SOP054"}

\cleardoublepage{}
\include{Bibliography}
\cleardoublepage{}
\end{document}
```

How can I create labels that allow me to reference the PDF's, or do I need to reference the PDF bookmark? If so, how do I do it? Or am I missing something?

Comment: Please make your code into a Minimum (non-)Working Example. This means people can copy it, paste it and compile it to recreate the issue you are seeing. At the very least, add `\documentclass...` and `\begin{document}` together with essential packages such as `pdfpages` (since `\includepdf` presumably uses it).